# Is there any way I can build muscle mass being a vegan?

Tags: workout, muscle-mass

Is there any way I can build muscle mass being a vegan?
The proteins from veggies are somehow limited

Comment: in the [help] it tells you to search for your question before posting: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=vegan+gain

Answer (score 1):

If you pick the right source, you'd get ample amount of protein. There are also supplements for protein, but those are just to compensate what you lack from your food. Your primary aim should be to eat good. Nuts, tubers, certain grains, soy, veggies would help you attain your protein requirements, but remember, your diet should consist of all nutrients in proper amount. Body grows when it gets overall nutrition, not just protein. Just eat proper and workout. There are many vegan bodybuilders, if you want to look up see what they eat, that may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

The very same way an omnivore would. Eat more calories. If you are lacking protein then there are vegan protein powders if you want to take that route. Otherwise eat more foods that contain proteins.

There is no work around this. There are vegan power lifters, so being vegan is not what is stopping you achieving your goal.